# Wireless network(s) not available when booting ubuntu 12.04 desktop 64 bit from usb flash drive

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I'm trying to connect to my wireless network at home after "trying" Ubuntu 12.04 desktop 64-bit from a USB flash drive (without installing). Is this even possible? I can connect to the Internet through my ethernet port just fine but wireless is not working. I have checked my BIOS settings and my wireless switches are enabled. I have a Dell Latitude D830. Any help would be appreciated since my hard drive just crashed and I ordered a new one but for now the only way to connect to the Internet is through Ubuntu, booted from a USB device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need drivers, are called *firmware* in Linux lingo. Try connecting your laptop with Ethernet and using the Additional Drivers tool (just search it in the dash). It will most likely find a driver for your machine.

If not, you may want to visit the [Ubuntu Wireless Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide) or even [the site of the old Intel® PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Driver project](http://ipw3945.sourceforge.net/).

This latter option may be quite difficult if you are not a power user (involving intricacies with the kernel and heavy use of the terminal), but may be tried as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried the additional drivers tool and it finds a drive which I can activate. However, it then says that it requires a reboot which when I do it wipes out the settings when it boots again because settings are not saved when booting from a usb flash drive. Is there any way to activate the drivers/services from the command line without rebooting? I tried a couple of things but is telling me that it cannot make changes because is read only media. Here is what I've tried:   
    7  sudo make wlunload b43
    8  sudo modprobe b43

Comment: @RZBoris You do this once you install Ubuntu fully. You don't need WiFi to install it. The good news is that it has found a driver, which will operate properly and be kept after a reboot if you do it on a fully installed system.

Comment: If you want to use Ubuntu form a flash drive, you can burn the setup disk to a CD and then use advanced partition setup to install Ubuntu to your Flash drive or external HDD(I often do this, just be careful to install to the right place :-)

Comment: ok thanks for the tips. So looks like the only way to use wireless is by installing stuff, i was hoping to use wireless without much issues for a couple of days until I get my new hard drive. oh well :-)thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have multiple flash drives, you can use one as the installer and install to the other.